# Why the $('tr td:eq(3)') only affects the first row?

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

Try to click on the `a4` and `b4`, it works for `a4` but not for `b4`. Is there any solution to let `b4` also has the event listener?

```js
$('tr td:eq(3)').click(function() {
  $(this).text(Math.random());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:eq()` is some [jquery specifc (deprecated!) selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
As per documentation, it only selects **one** element with index n.

If you want to select every 3rd td in every row, use normal CSS selectors: Note the change from 3 to 4, because nth-child is <s>0</s> 1 based where eq() seems to be <s>1</s> 0 based.

```js
$('tr td:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
  $(this).text(Math.random());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `:nth-child)` is 1-based, `:eq()` is zero-based.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am using jQuery 3.6 but `eq()` still works for me. Do I really have to remove all of my `eq` selectors?

Comment: `.eq()` is not the same as `:eq()`  `.eq()` is not deprecated, but `:eq()` is.

Answer (score 0):

use a comma separated list of those you want to target 3 (the 4th one - 'a4'), 7 (the 8th one - 'b4')

```
$('tr td:eq(3), tr td:eq(7)').click(function(){
  $(this).text(Math.random());
});
```

Alternatively add a class to the target ones and use that as the selector instead

```
$('tr td.common-class').click(function(){
  $(this).text(Math.random());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [jQuery's deprecated `:eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (which does *Select the element at index n within the matched set*) function, use a fitting selector:

```js
$('td:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
  $(this).text(Math.random());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Even though that works, you really don't need jQuery for that. Here's the vanilla JS DOM API version of it:

```js
for (const cell of document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(4)')) {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.textContent = Math.random();
  })
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>a4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>b3</td>
      <td>b4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```